# Проверка существования в таблице со связью в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM bbb_rrr as br 
LEFT JOIN bbb as b 
ON br.bbb_id = b.id 
AND b.act = 1 
AND br.user_id = ?
```

Когда я выполняю этот запрос, он срабатывает, хотя записи в `bbb_rrr` нет.
Пробовал также добавлять разные условия `WHERE`, но результат один и тот-же.

Нужно, чтобы запрос проверял, есть - ли в таблице `bbb_rrr` запись, которая в таблице `bbb` с флагом `act = 1` ну и конечно же, что она вообще создана от текущего ида пользователя...

Надеюсь, что понятно объяснил.

То есть если запись есть по условию запроса, показываем, если нет. то `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, в итоге вышло так:

```
SELECT b.*, br.*
FROM bbb as b 
LEFT JOIN bbb_rrr as br 
ON br.bbb_id = b.id 
WHERE b.id = ? 
AND b.act = 1
AND br.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с Join вместо Left join и кривого условия в on и where:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bbb_rrr as br 
JOIN bbb as b 
ON br.bbb_id = b.id
WHERE br.user_id = ?
AND b.act = 1
```

[Фиддл тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f8525fda0a5906951ada130bd553979)

Answer (score 0):

Правильным будет следующий запрос:

```
SELECT b.id, case when br.bbb_id is null then 'false' else 'true' end as exists 
FROM bbb as b 
LEFT JOIN bbb_rrr as br ON br.bbb_id = b.id 
WHERE b.id = ?  
AND b.act = 1
```

Comment: а где пропала проверка user_id?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под  _проверка user_id_?

Comment: Смотрите вопрос и пример кода в нем